# C++ memory model and maximal sequence of bit fields

Tags: c++, bit-fields, memory-model

The example bellow appears in both Stroustrup's and CPPreference websites:

```
struct S {
        char a;         // location #1
        int b:5,        // location #2
        int c:11,
        int :0,         // note: :0 is "special"
        int d:8;        // location #3
        struct {int ee:8;} e;   // location #4
    };
```

Considering the definition of *memory location* provided by the C++ standard:

- An object of scalar type;
- The largest contiguous sequence of bit fields of non-zero length.

It is quite clear that:

- 'a' is one location;
- 'b-c' is another location;
- 'd' is the start of a new location.

However it is not clear to me, considering the definition above, why 'd-ee' or 'd-e' is not a single location, but two instead.

References:

- https://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#memory-model
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model

Comment: technically bit fields are not guaranteed to be contiguous. All they have is permission to have a non-unique memory location. Even physical order of fields is not defined by standard (and in most implementations it depends on endianness). *Memory locations* they occupy will be contiguous, i.e. adjacent, but bit-wise there might be gaps (0-sized field is a special case to guarantee the leap)

Comment: As Swift's answer notes, there is actually a syntax error in the C++11 FAQ! Either you use a semicolon between the fields but include `int` each time, or use a comma between fields but *don't* include `int` after the first declaration. The cppreference.com example and actual standard does not include this error. But of course that doesn't affect your actual question.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard ([6.7.1 intro.memory](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.memory)) uses extremely similar language and even exactly the same example:

> ... or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width ...
>
> [ Example: A class declared as
>
> ```
> struct {
>   char a;
>   int b:5,
>   c:11,
>   :0,
>   d:8;
>   struct {int ee:8;} e;
> }
> ```
>
> contains four separate memory locations: The member `a` and bit-fields `d` and `e.ee` are each separate memory locations ...

One difference is that it uses the word "adjacent" rather than "contiguous".

Are `d` and `ee` *contiguous*? The word "contiguous" literally means without gaps in between, which seems to suggest it's talking about memory layout (do they have padding between?). But this is the part of the standard that defines memory layout, so it would be circular if it defined things in terms of this! This is a very poor choice of word and seems to be the source of the confusion.

Are `d` and `ee` *adjacent*? This is certainly a better word since it's more obviously about the code rather than about memory layout, but I think you could still interpret it so that the answer is either yes or no in this case. But given that there is an example that shows they're not, we have to accept "adjacent" as a shorthand for "fields whose definitions are adjacent to each other directly within the same struct".

Comment: This question of wording is a very interesting point, indeed probably the source of confusion. We are dealing here with C++ definitions (in the language) and the underlying memory model (outside the language though still abstract, i.e., architecture independent).

Answer (score 0):

First, there is syntax error, bit-fields are separate declarations.

```
struct S {
        char a;         // location #1 and storage of subobject a
        int b:5;        // location #2, beginning of new sequence

        int c:11;
        int :0;         // note: :0 is "special", it ends sequence of fields
        int d:8;        // location #3, beginning of new sequence

        struct {        // storage of subobject e, sequence of fields is over
           int ee:8;    // location #4 within e
        } e;   
    };
```

Order of locations for fields is implementation-defined.

In terms of C++ definitions `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` are separate objects. But `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` are allowed to share memory-locations (physical words or bytes) within a contiguous sequence of locations because they are bit fields, albeit `e` is  an object of class type and must have a unique memory location. Non-static member `ee` is sub-object of `e`, which means it occupies part of `e`'s storage, so it is guaranteed to be a separate memory location.

As a result of non-uniqueness you can take address (`operator&`) of `e`, but not `d` or `ee`.

Comment: I understand the arguments, however, 'e' is not a scalar nor a bit field. So strictly speaking it falls out of the definition of *memory location*. We can, on the other hand, recurse the concept inside the inner struct, finding a bit field. And then we have neighbors bit fields in the end.

Comment: `e` is not being one, so it can't be same location as any preceding it bit fields, though it's content is *a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width*, specifically a single field `ee`. So `ee` is a separate location within a separate object.